# How is the load balancer works, when i have an established Web socket connection and the server is full or busy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elb

I have a wss localhost url, I want to know that, if a client has established a websocket connection with server and later the server is busy or full with requests and not able to accept new requests, then how is the load balancer(AWS) handles the request with new instance ?
I am new to AWS, i don't know if AWS instance can transfer all the websocket connection to new clone.

Comment: They will time out and wss will be closed. client will have to establish new one to new instance. ELB will not be transfering any connections to new instances.

Comment: My client is a Raspberry pi and sending Boot Notification to server for the first time, then sending Heartbeats.So in this case client should send again a Boot notification request to the server right ?

Comment: yes. That's why you should develop your app to be stateless. If any instance is down, other can continue. All state information are stored, e.g. in DynamoDb.